# This code works on PyCharm but not on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

This question is 3 years old: [Code is working in pyCharm but not in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962922/code-is-working-in-pycharm-but-not-in-visual-studio-code)

So, maybe this is the reason why it doesn't work anymore. Anyway, I have this project structure:

[image]

It works perfectly when I run "main.py" under "01SpaceInvaders", but the same code in vscode returns this error:

```
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\salva\Documents\VS Code\pysandbox\game\01SpaceInvaders\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from game.sdfengine.locals import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'game'
```

For sure, there is a configuration missing in my VSCode, but I don't know what. Any clue?

This is how I execude the code from VSCode:

1. I open a new terminal
2. Go to `01SpaceInvaders`
3. `py main.py`

Following the comments it seems VSCode configuration problem:

Where can I find the file to edit and a guide to understand how to edit it?

Comment: How exactly are you executing it? You just have the wrong working directory and/or environment path settings…

Comment: Well, you need to be in the directory `pysandbox` and run `game/01SpaceInvaders/main.py`, if you want `game` to be found.

Comment: alternatively you can add the `pysandbox` directory to your PYTHONPATH environment variable. I don't know the windows syntax to do that

Comment: @Almog-at-Nailo so the problem is configuration as I thought. That means that does VSCode's project to be configured to works?
Where can I find this file to edit and a guide?

Comment: You can try any of the solutions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages notice you would want to add the pysandbox path and not the python binary path to your PYTHONPATH environment variable

Comment: Found a more official answer from python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that python does not know where to find the directory called `game` since it is not an installed python library (it's a directory in your project structure)

To let python know of directories that it should consider as libraries to import from you can use the environment variable PYTHONPATH (see documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables))

You can:

1. configure your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable temporarily from command line:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Users\salva\Documents\VS Code\pysandbox
```

2. configure it permanently on windows by searching for "edit environment variables" in your start menu
3. edit your vscode `settings.json` file (see documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles)) ctrl + shift + p -> "open user settings (JSON)" and add:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${env:PYTHONPATH};C:\\your\\path\\here"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The most straightforward way is to indicate the path by adding the following at the top of the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./")
```

[image]

You can also configure **PYTHONPATH** using `.env` file

Comment: You should _not_ need to edit all your code files to futz with the path. You just need to execute your program using the right environment path settings.

Comment: Can VSCode not deal with this in a run configuration, like PyCharm can? That seems better than requiring users to pollute their source code.